# Change default API path for Ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I started my Hadoop Sandbox from Hortonworks.

I'm trying to use Ambari API. Every response contains `href`:

```
"href" : "http://sandbox-hdp-security:8080/api/v1/...",
```

I would like to change returned address to something more like (of course not only `href` but also rest of returned API paths):

```
"href" : "http://11.11.11.11:8080/api/v1/...",
```

(my custom IP Address).

I looked into `/etc/ambari-server/conf`, `/etc/ambari-agent/conf` and Ambari web configuration, but no luck. I didn't find any documentation about API configuration.

It may be important - it's Sandbox on VM, but I mapped all important ports outside so it should be available from network (and `<ip>:8080` is available).

**EDIT (1):**
I checked my `/etc/hosts` and DNS configurations. Nothing there suggests existance  of `sandbox-hdp-secure` host. I used `grep` to find this string on whole HDP Sandbox and it only appeared in logs. I don't know how it's Ambari host when nothing on server suggest that setting.

I found also this script on web:

> http://codegists.com/snippet/shell/gist56b5cfdb81ef828ba1a6aec6306d8da6_paul-lupu_shell

If it's legit Hortonworks script then this problematic name (`sandbox-hdp-security`) is changed at start of server, but Ambari still uses its. I tested it on my second HDP Sandbox VM and result was the same (Ambari returns this name as host).

I could try to change router DNS to map `sandbox-hdp-security` to my IP, but I'm sure that Ambari should let me set returned host.

Comment: This is an /etc/hosts or a DNS change, nothing really to do with Hadoop or Ambari. You should be using the external DNS name, though, unless your IP is static and will never change

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your insight. I checked `hosts` earlier, but didn't test DNS. I updated my question with more details.

Comment: I known the Ambari **agent** config files need to point at the server address, but the server itself I'm fairly sure is just a DNS change. Though I've not used the sandbox in years

Comment: @cricket_007 I found this setting for agent and changed it (and broke few things). Maybe it's only DNS setting, but I can't figure out how to change it. And it's interesting that name returned by API isn't appearing in files...